# Promises returning pending

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having slight issues with promises in typescript where the results is always pending, even though it's been fulfilled.

I have this function in a utils folder that processes endpoints from another file, which all run on promises

utils folder function

```
export const GetData = async (
    xx: string[],
    endpointOne: boolean,
) => {
    if (endpointOne) {
        return getDataFromEndpointOne(xx)
    } 

    return getDataFromEndpointTwo(xx)
}
```

example of endpoint

```
const getDataFromEndpointOne = (
    xx: string[],
): Promise<any> =>
    Request(
        `/endpoint1/${xx}`,
    );
```

But in the main folder that's calling the utils folder function, it always (always) returns pending no matter what I try

```
const data =
    getData(
        ["1", "3", "56"],
        true
    ).then(result => { return result })
```

Comment: What's `Request`?

Comment: Sorry, my own wrapper around axios

Comment: `data` will be the promise returned by `then`. You can't *synchronously* get a value that is only provided *asynchronously*. You need to use the data in the `then` callback. (Side note: `.then(x => { return x; })` is pointless.)

Comment: If the code where `const data =` is located at the top level of a JavaScript (ESM) module, and your environment supports [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) [all modern browsers and most modern bundlers do], you could so `const data = await getData(/*...*/);` Note that it delays loading of your module until the promise returned by `getData` settles.

Comment: Side note: If you don't use `await` in a function, there's no real reason for it to be marked `async`. Your `getData`, for instance, doesn't need `async` (not as shown).

Comment: ^^^ thank you @T.J.Crowder